# Передача данных после сигнала post_save

Tags: django

Вьюха принимающая request с фронта

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from shop.signals import * #мой сигнал


class CodeCompare(View):
    def post(self, request):
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        body_unicode = json.loads(body_unicode)
        email = body_unicode['email']
        phone = body_unicode['phone']
        code = body_unicode['code']
        form = UserCreationForm({"username": email, "password1": phone, "password2":phone })
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

Функция-сигнал, работает по `post_save`

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_customer(sender, instance, created,  **kwargs):
    print('Сигнал о том что пользователь создан')
    print(instance.username)
```

В первой части кода есть переменная `code`, и я ее не буду записывать в `User`, будет еще ряд параметров которые я туда не буду записывать. Но в сигнале я буду обращаться к новой модели `Customer` и создавать еще один экземпляр, и я хочу записать все параметры которые придут ко мне с фронта, обращаясь к `instance` я могу достать лишь те поля которые записаны в `User`, а как передать еще ряд значение в сигнал во время вызова сигнала?

Comment: Записывать в бд нужно.

Comment: а другие варианты, меня интересует что нить на лету?

Comment: Думаю, можно кешировать.

Comment: кешировать? так же можно и в сессию запихнуть если в таком ключе, а что быстрее? не знаете?

Comment: там есть аргумент в виде kwargs, вот я все на него гляжу можно ли в него запихнуть что бы достать в сигнале. Пробовал объявлять во вьюхе, но безуспешно, не пойму как это работает, мне кажется что все таки есть более простые способы передачи информации в сигнал.

Comment: Попробуйте, я так не делал никогда. `kwargs['code] = body_unicode['code']`. А в сигнале `kwargs.pop('code')`

Comment: не работает это содержимое kwargs в signal {'raw': False, 'using': 'default', 'update_fields': None, 'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x7ffaab1c97f0>}